# faster imagemagick operations for appending 2 png and 1 gif side by side without as gif

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have this operation and I was wondering if this ImageMagick script can be faster significantly?

The intention is to append 2 png and 1 gif side by side

Inputs

[image: png 1]
[image: png 2]
[image: png 3]

Expected result.

[image]

```
time (convert sample/1/1.png sample/1/1.gif &&
convert sample/1/2.png sample/1/2.gif &&
convert sample/1/1.gif -repage 900x169 -coalesce \
        null: \( sample/1/2.gif -coalesce \) -geometry +300+0 -layers Composite -coalesce \
        null: \( sample/1/3.gif -coalesce \) -geometry +600+0 -layers Composite  -coalesce \
        result.gif && mogrify -layers 'optimize' -fuzz 10% result.gif)
```

```
real    0m1.346s
user    0m1.835s
sys     0m0.399s
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mpr helps.

```
time (
convert \
sample/1/1.png -write mpr:tmp1 +delete \
sample/1/2.png -write mpr:tmp2 +delete \
mpr:tmp1 -repage 900x169 -coalesce \
null: \( mpr:tmp2 -coalesce \) -geometry +300+0 -layers Composite -coalesce \
null: \( sample/1/3.gif -coalesce \) -geometry +600+0 -layers Composite -coalesce \
-write mpr:tmp3 +delete -layers 'optimize' -fuzz 10% result.gif
)
```

```
real    0m0.358s
user    0m0.618s
sys     0m0.087s
```

Comment: Your -fuzz 10% at the end does nothing. It needs an operator following it such as -trim to make use of it.  What do you want -fuzz to do in this context?  As you seem to only use mpr:tmp1 and mpr:tmp2 each only once, why do you even need to write the mpr: images? Since your mpr:tmp1 and mpr:tmp2 are png, they both only have one image. So your first null: ... -layers composite is not needed and could be replace by a simple -composite with no need to -coalesce either. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Without having your images to use, the following is untested, since I do not know quite what you are expecting. Nevertheless as per my comment above, in ImageMagick, try the following.

However, I am not sure why you need the first -repage. What are you trying to achieve with that?

(If the following works as you intended, then does it work if you remove -repage 1200x360 or use -set page 1200x360?)

```
time convert \
sample/1/1.png -repage 1200x360 sample/1/2.png -geometry +358+0 -composite \
null: \( sample/1/3.gif -coalesce \) -geometry +842+0 -layers Composite \
-layers optimize result.gif
```